# using igraph in R to draw a random sample of (connected) triads

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I have a large (i.e., 14 million vertices) undirected igraph object and want to draw a random sample of all fully connected triads (A-B-C-A) and of all partially connected triads (A-B-C).

I can get their number using `triad_census`, but I need the actual vertex IDs.

Currently, I draw a random set of of IDs i, j, and k and then check if they're connected. But clearly the performance isn't very good, as most aren't connected at and it takes large numbers to get a sample of connected ones.

Is there a better or built-in way of doing this?

Setup:

```
library(igraph)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(50000, 0.00035, type = "gnp")
// Here I need to generate a data.frame with columns i, j, and k. Containing the vertex IDs of (a sample of) connected triads.
```

Comment: triangles(graph) will provide counts or lists of all triangles in the graph

Comment: igraph's motif finder (`igraph_motifs_randesu_callback()`) is a perfect fit for this job, and will be able to do it efficiently, while guaranteeing uniform sampling. However, the relevant functionality is not yet exposed in R. I suggest you put in a feature request, https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/new/choose, and explain your use case in detail.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like the perfect tool. Based on what you wrote, I assume there's no direct way to access it from R?

Comment: What you can do from R is _count_ how many closed and open triplets there are, but unless I missed something, the functionality to actually list them is not yet exposed. You can use it from C, or from Python, see https://python.igraph.org/en/stable/api/igraph.GraphBase.html#motifs_randesu  The `callback` parameter takes a function that will be called with each found triplet. The `cut_prob` parameter can be used to do random sampling instead of exhaustive enumeration. See the cited paper, as well as what I wrote on estimating counts: http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igmotifs

Answer (score 1):

In the iGraph library, there is the following function:

> triangles() lists all triangles of a graph. For efficiency, all
> triangles are returned in a single vector. The first three vertices
> belong to the first triangle, etc.

This will provide your list of all triangles.
For all triads which form a *path* and not a triangle, I can not find a built-in function but it is not hard to do yourself. Instead of a triple for-loop looking at every triplet of vertices in the graph, we can use one for-loop to look at each vertex and find when that vertex is the midpoint of the 3-node-path.

More specifically: for every vertex `v` in the graph, look at its neighbourhood (which is quite small with your small `p` value). Look at all pairs in the neighbourhood and every pair `x,y` which are not adjacent will form the endpoints of your open triad: `x-v-y`.

Comment: Now that you added the scale that you are working with (approx 14 million nodes) many standard approaches to networks of that size are no longer feasible. People often break down their network into a sampling of egonets (the subnetwork which is centred upon an individual node... that is, a subnetwork which is the neighbourhood of one vertex). You might want to structure your analysis around that sort of framework.

Comment: If you can obtain the clustering coefficient of your nodes (a.k.a. transitivity coefficient, a built-in function in iGraph), you could find your partial triads by looking at the nodes with low (non-zero) clustering coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

- For fully-connected triads, we can use `triangles`, which gives all triangles and their vertices

```
# all fully-connected triads and one sample
all_full_triads <- matrix(triangles(g), 3)
sample_full_triads <- all_full_triads[, sample.int(ncol(all_full_triads), 1)]
```

- For all partial-connected triads, we can use `distances` to find the vertex pairs that are of distance `2` (that means we mush has another vertex in between to construct the partial-connected triads), and then use `all_shortest_paths` to produce all the partial-connected triads

```
# all partial-connected triads, starting from finding the vertex pairs of distance 2
d <- as.data.frame(which(distances(g) == 2, arr.ind = TRUE))
all_partial_triads <- apply(
    subset(d, row < col), 1,
    \(x) all_shortest_paths(g, from = x[["row"]], to = x[["col"]])$res
)
```

## Example

Given a toy network as below

```
set.seed(0)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(8, 0.5, type = "gnp")
```

[image]

We can achieve

```
> all_full_triads
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    2    2
[2,]    2    2    8    8    8    7    5
[3,]    7    5    7    4    5    6    6

> sample_full_triads
[1] 2 7 6

> d
   row col
1    3   1
2    6   1
3    4   2
4    8   2
5    1   3
6    4   3
7    5   3
8    6   3
9    7   3
10   2   4
11   3   4
12   5   4
13   7   4
14   3   5
15   4   5
16   7   5
17   1   6
18   3   6
19   8   6
20   3   7
21   4   7
22   5   7
23   2   8
24   6   8

> all_partial_triads
$`5`
$`5`[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 1 8 3

$`5`[[2]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 1 2 3


$`10`
$`10`[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 2 1 4


$`11`
$`11`[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 3 8 4


$`14`
$`14`[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 3 8 5

$`14`[[2]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 3 2 5


$`15`
$`15`[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 4 8 5

$`15`[[2]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 4 1 5


$`17`
$`17`[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 1 7 6

$`17`[[2]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 1 5 6

$`17`[[3]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 1 2 6


$`18`
$`18`[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 3 2 6


$`20`
$`20`[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 3 8 7

$`20`[[2]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 3 2 7


$`21`
$`21`[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 4 8 7

$`21`[[2]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 4 1 7


$`22`
$`22`[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 5 8 7

$`22`[[2]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 5 6 7

$`22`[[3]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 5 2 7

$`22`[[4]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 5 1 7


$`23`
$`23`[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 2 7 8

$`23`[[2]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 2 5 8

$`23`[[3]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 2 3 8

$`23`[[4]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 2 1 8


$`24`
$`24`[[1]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 6 7 8

$`24`[[2]]
+ 3/8 vertices, from ec0b7da:
[1] 6 5 8
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. Unfortunately, the thing for the partial triangles already breaks down with slightly larger networks (e.g., `erdos.renyi.game(200000,p=1e-5)`) as it is rather memory intensive.